# How to hide urls from appearing in the address bar (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, http, web

I am developing an embedded web server. Now, I have an access validation page (e.g. http://192.168.1.1/) at the very start that accepts username and password and validates it and later redirects the users to the actual device control web page (http://192.168.1.1/devicecontrol.html). I do not want the actual url to appear on the address bar. Instead the initial url should be retained so that users cannot directly visit this page and neither be able to bookmark this page....I understand this must be a common requirement but could not find any specific answers to this...any help / references would be hugely appreciated....Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you *need* to do this? Is there a reason you don't want to show people the URL?

Comment: It's not a common requirement to block your users from bookmarking your site :)

Comment: You usually want them to KEEP coming back to your site...!

Comment: Guys the person here is probably developing an embedded server to run on an embedded device the vistor of which will be a single person and not the masses. Use case is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with Javascript alone. Use a Frameset (or if you're using Apache take a look at the [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)).

One more advice: **Don't do it!** I would leave your site immediately, when I click around and the URL doesn't change. Looks like you're hiding something.

Comment: I thought I had made it pretty clear in my question as to why I need to do this...its to disallow users to directly visit some pages that are confidential without logging in...